# Animation on Layout Android Code

Tags: android, animation, layout

I am a newbie android developer.

**In some application, mainly Iphone magazine or others, they have feature animation on each thumbnail news. ( When user click on the news, the small article with thumbnail image will zoom or stretch to full screen of the phone)**

Sorry It's hard to explain, anyway that's the concept.

I'm not sure what this feature call in android.

**EDITED**

For example, I have a relative layout in the middle of the screen. This relative layout contains an image and textview components.

**What I want to do is when user click on this layout, The layout BECOME BIGGER and BIGGER (animation) until it stretch the phone screen.**

Thank,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't get your requirement but i [here](http://www.bogotobogo.com/Android/android19Animation.php) is the animation examples for `Layout` and `frame` animation.